# How do I leverage existing C# (.NET 4.5.x) in a .net-core (DotNetCore 1.0) application

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've got a netcoreapp1.0 (Microsoft.NETCore.App) application that is a kestrel based web service and I'd like to leverage some of my existing C# DLLs (.NET 4.5.x)  I also have a few other netstandard1.6 (NETStandard.Library) assemblies that I'm using.
The big question: is it possible to pull in legacy code without porting it all to DotNetCore 1.0?

Breaking it down, I suppose I'd like to know:

1. What is the correct framework target for my application?  I'm assuming it has to be netcoreapp1.0 rather than net451.
2. What imports (ex. dnxcore50, net451) does my application require?
3. What additions need to be made to my C# assembly?  Is a project.json sufficient or does having an xproj provide some additional value?
4. What is the correct framework target for my C# assembly?  I'm assuming NETStandard.Library 1.6.0 is wrong since I believe it would require code changes to get compiling.

Any suggestions and/or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms) for fx compatability.

Comment: Should your app be platform agnostic, i.e. should it also be able to run on linux, mac? Are you tied to a specific framework version?

Comment: Legends, thanks!  Very windows specific.  Basically I want to couple ASP.NET Core with my existing windows C# code.  Cross platform comes later.

Comment: Legends - I had seen the compatibility page before but maybe i misread it.  I assumed the chart was saying that 4.5.1/4.5.2 was compatible with netcoareapp 1.0 and netstandard 1.2+ .  Is it really saying that 4.6.3 is compatible with 1.0 and 1.6?  I suspect upgrading from 4.5.1 to 4.6.3 will be a trivial upgrade for me so I'll try that out shortly.

Comment: If you have a dependency that requires net451+ your application needs to target net451+. You can force taking the net451 dependency in a netcoreapp1.0 (which is what imports is for) but it will most likely fail at runtime. imports only makes sense if you know that the package will work with netcoreapp (typically it was shipped for dnxcore50 but was not updated or was a PCL).

Comment: I know, it is really confusing, for me too. I would agree with you regarding the compatability things. Choose a .net core web application (new project) which targets the full .net framework --> v.4.6.3. This should work fine with .net standard 1.6 libraries. The lower the .net standard lib version is, the lower will be the functionality you will have available in that projects. 
You can also target multiple frameworks in your web app, but i guess you have to use compiler directives in your code then...

Comment: Some of my issues are being confounded by the complexity of the code I'm working with.  Today I took the route of creating a new solution with a net46 console app (.net core app targeting net46), a net46 class library, and a C# class library.  I added a project.json to the C# library that sets the framework target to net46.  I had to remove some of the using directives from the net46 class library to get it to build, but this appears to dotnet restore correctly, and fails with a single build error: the C# library (library2.dll) could not be found.

Comment: I still need to evaluate the overhead of getting my existing C# working in DotNetCore but the trivial example gives me hope that running existing C#.NET in DotNetCore 1.0 is viable.

Comment: Everything works as expected if you accept that net46 can't run under netstandard1.6.  That is, if my DotNetCore app, DotNetCore library, and C#.NET library all target net46 it all works as expected.  The disappointing part here is that your app won't be able to leverage any cross-platform netstandard1.6 stuff (AFAIK).  The good news is that all I need to do to leverage my existing C#.NET code in a DotNetCore net4.6 app is add a project.json file. Thanks everyone!  I will throw out one more question for the sake of posterity...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/frameworks "framework Versions" section suggests that .NET 4.6.1 is an implementation of .NET standard 1.4.  This suggests to me that .NET 4.6.1 would be a strict superset of .NET standard 1.4.  If this is true, why can't I use netstandard 1.4 assemblies in a DotNetCore app that targets .NET 4.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

Since the meat of the work was all in comments...here's a summary of the answer:

Everything works as expected if you accept that net46 can't run under netstandard1.6. That is, if my DotNetCore app, DotNetCore library, and C#.NET library all target net46 it works as expected.